# Asp.net c# Active Directory login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a web app using .net 4.0 and Active Directory `UserPrincipal` to login.

It works pretty much for everyone, except this one user. Whenever he tries, he always gets the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
>   at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyValueCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)

What might be wrong? the code or his account.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a full exception stack trace?

Comment: It means that the property you are trying to access on the returned user account doesn't exist. For example, if you are trying to access their e-mail address or display name. One of your lines of code that reads something like that is failing.

Comment: Can you provide full code for where you make the call please

Comment: Thank you TimS,
It is very simple piece of code:

Comment: <code>Dim adPath As String = "my active directory path"
            Try

                Dim entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(adPath, myUserName, mypassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
                Dim directorySearch As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
                directorySearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=" & myUserName & "))"
                Dim results As SearchResult = directorySearch.FindOne()
                If Not results Is Nothing Then
                    'found
                End If
           End Try</code>